# Cannot install Tensorflow on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pip

System Information
MacBook Air M1
Ubuntu Linux 20.04 using virtual machine
Python 3.8.5 64 bits

I have already installed tensor flow but after importing the library and compiling any code it gives me the following set of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/Desktop/IP/image.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
mradulagrawal@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/mradulagrawal/Desktop/IP/image.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/Desktop/IP/image.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/mradulagrawal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Thank You!

Comment: How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, the problem occurred in the relevant files of the installed module "tensorflow".

It is recommended that you find the installation package folder of the module "tensorflow" in this python environment and try to delete it, then reinstall it to avoid damage or incompatibility of some files.

We can use "`pip show module`" to find the installation location of the module:

[image]

[image]